# How can I move text files in each folder to new folder at once using sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2

[image]

I am using sublime text editor, and beginner. 
I know there is way, but can anyone tell me how to change R-text files in each folder to R file using sublime? 
In other words, Ex02_03.R, EX02_04.R, and so one, I want to move them to R file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you switch over to sublime text 3, you can use [this plugin(SideBarEnhancements)](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) to achieve those functionalities. The plugin use to be available on sublime text 2. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/issues/172) to figure out a work around.

There is also [sublime text quick file move](https://github.com/wulftone/sublime-text-quick-file-move) available for Sublime text 2.

Answer (score -1):

You can search in directory for `*.R` files using **File Explorer** and cut those file >> create new folder >> paste.

1) You only need the mouse to copy-paste. :)